# How to pick a step down transformer for powering MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, power, transformer, relay

I need to select a transformer to power my microcontroller, relay, 7 seg display and few LEDs. The maximum current draw will be 300mA. I doubled that to improve reliability. So the AC current works out to be around 860mA(0.7 x DC current).

My questions are:

1. Do I need a 100% safety margin for the current?
2. There are lot of options for transformers. As low as $1 from eBay to $10 from mouser. What makes them different if they are rated for same voltage and current?
3. What are the safety components I should look for in a transformer to ensure that it does not injure some one, cause fire or some catastrophe when it fails? I have included a fuse as the first thing when mains enter the product.

Thank you!

Comment: You almost certainly *do not* want to design your own linear AC/DC power supply.  Buy something (connectorized product or sub-module) proven and safe designed by someone experienced, today probably a switcher unless it is extremely sensitive AM radio gear.  Most such projects basically end up running on a quality phone "charger" 5v power supply.  Anyway, the question as you have posted it is far too broad and multi-part to fit here; you're basically asking for a *tutorial* on designing power supplies - and *obsolete* power supplies at that.

Answer (score 2):

At the 300mA current level you'll be throwing away a lot of power in the regulator, so I second Chris's suggestion to use a switching power supply wall wart or module.

Anyway, the rule of thumb is that you need a transformer RMS AC rating that is 62% higher than the DC current requirement. So for 300mA you'd need 440mA, call it 500mA or better.

As far as the existence of price differences they often occur due to different distribution schemes and more important issues such as safety agency approvals for various parts of the world. The approvals may be a routine thing, but more likely the unapproved transformer uses materials or techniques that are sub-par. That is also true of switching power supply modules, perhaps to an even greater degree.

Any transformer (or other mains connected device) can create heat and smoke. Keeping it within a grounded metal housing and properly fused will reduce the risk. Commercial AC adapters that omit the fuse and have a plastic enclosure are carefully designed to fail in a relatively benign way (the ones with genuine approval markings are anyway).

Comment: Look for isolation transformers if you want to design your own thing.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. If I were to build it myself, I should select a transformer with secondary current rating above 500mA, a class B insulation and properly fuse both the primary and secondary. Would it be a safe design?

Comment: The transformer should be safety-agency marked to ensure primary-secondary insulation integrity - potential shock hazard.